# NSURLSessionUploadTask failed to upload file

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Below is snippet for uploading a image file.I want to use NSURLSessionUploadTask only,because it gives background upload feature which i want to use in my app.

Also i want to POST parameter along with file upload.

Also i am not good in server side code.Can anyone please guide me what am i doing wrong.

**Upload Code**

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"jpg"];
uint64_t bytesTotalForThisFile = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL] fileSize];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadPath];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", bytesTotalForThisFile] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setTimeoutInterval:30];

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"jpg"];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *taskUpload= [self.uploadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$objFile = & $_FILES["file"];
$strPath = basename( $objFile["name"] );

if( move_uploaded_file( $objFile["tmp_name"], $strPath ) ) {
    print "The file " .  $strPath . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

From Server side i am getting empty array for $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

I will put an example of code. Check if you get any error on console.

```
// 1. config
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

// 2. if necessary set your Authorization HTTP (example api)
// [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"<setYourKey>":<value>}];

// 3. Finally, you create the NSURLSession using the above configuration.
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

// 4. Set your Request URL
NSURL *url = <yourURL>;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

// 5. Set your HTTPMethod POST or PUT
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

// 6. Encapsulate your file (supposse an image)
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

// 7. You could try use uploadTaskWithRequest fromData
NSURLSessionUploadTask *taskUpload = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    if (!error && httpResp.statusCode == 200) {

        // Uploaded

    } else {

       // alert for error saving / updating note
       NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ AND HTTPREST ERROR : %ld", error, (long)httpResp.statusCode);
      }
}];
```

Comment: I am using background session not default, Also completion handler are not allowed in background session.Also NSData as image is not allowed as image.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the complete code, then you aren't actually **starting** the upload.  *NSURLSession* tasks are not started automatically (unlike some *NSURLConnection* calls).  You have to explicitly call their resume method to start the upload, or the tasks will just sit there and do nothing.

Second, you should really be using *URLForResource* rather than using a path and then converting it to a URL.  That shouldn't break your code, but it is a lot cleaner to just use URLs to begin with.

Third, if you really do need to use a path, convenience methods (*fileURLWithPath:*) are your friend.

Fourth, you don't need to set *Content-Length*, and IIRC, you probably shouldn't, because you don't know what the content length will actually be if NSURLSession negotiates any sort of encoding (e.g. compressing the file data).

Fifth, if the file is large, 30 seconds might not be long enough.

Sixth, if you're running on newer versions of iOS or OS X, be sure you are either using a properly configured HTTPS server or that you have added a suitable App Transport Security exception.

Finally, if you want to include other POST parameters rather than just providing the blob of data as the request body, you'll have to use a streaming request.  You can, of course, use GET parameters trivially, and that's what I would recommend that you do, because it is a much, much easier way to do things.  :-)